# Power BI Activity Log UpdateWorkspaceAccess

Tags: powerbi

When calling

```
Get-PowerBIActivityEvent -StartDateTime ($start) -EndDateTime ($end) -ActivityType UpdateWorkspaceAccess
```

I expected to get all changes to workspace access across all workspaces, similar to activity type ViewReport gives me all report views. For some reason it seems to return activity for the user I'm currently logged in as. Can't find any detailed docs on how  UpdateWorkspaceAccess is supposed to work.

Grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Did you try with user with Admin permission?

Answer (score 0):

Well normally this works for me

```
Get-PowerBIActivityEvent -StartDateTime 2021-12-21T00:00:00 -EndDateTime 2021-12-21T18:00:00 -ActivityType viewreport | Out-File –FilePath C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Process.json
```

You can also use Power BI Rest API :

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime={startDateTime}&endDateTime={endDateTime}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&$filter={$filter}
```

Comment: Question was specifically for the activity type "UpdateWorkspaceAccess"